# Custom webpack substitutions like [name], [id], [hash], but I want to build my own substitution

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Specifically, I want to build the tag `[camelCaseName]` that will convert file name (which is in snake case) to the camel case.

But I can't seem to find any instruction on how to build my own custom substitution. I wonder if anyone has some resources or examples around this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've figured it out from looking at the code that handles `[name]` (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js).

We can write a plugin that hooks in to `asset-path`.

```
const replacePathVariables = (path, data) => {
  const REGEXP_CAMEL_CASE_NAME = /\[camelcasename\]/gi;
    if (typeof path === "function") {
        path = path(data);
    }

  if (data && data.chunk && data.chunk.name) {
    return path.replace(
      REGEXP_CAMEL_CASE_NAME,
      data.chunk.name
        .replace(/(\-\w)/g, (matches) => { return matches[1].toUpperCase(); })
        .replace(/(^\w)/, (matches) => { return matches[0].toUpperCase(); })
    );
  } else {
    return path;
  }

};

class ExtraTemplatedPathPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin("compilation", function(compilation) {
            const mainTemplate = compilation.mainTemplate;
            mainTemplate.plugin('asset-path', replacePathVariables);
        });
    }
}
```

The code above supports replacing `[camelcasename]`.